# bootstrap menu dropdown not working with SPFX -extensions

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I have installed jquery and bootstrap to my spfx projects via npm.
The menu loads well but it seems i'm having issues with bootstrap js because when i click on the menu with dropdown(see screenshot below) it doesn't work
What am i missing and how should i be referencing the js and css.

Thanks in advance

My css is being loaded by using :-

```
SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://menu.sharepoint.com/sites/top/SiteAssets/SPFXBranding/bootstrap.min.css');
```

[image]

In my config.json i have declared external ref js

```
externals": {
    "jquery":"https://menu.sharepoint.com/sites/top/SiteAssets/SPFXBranding/jquery.min.js",
    "bootstrap":"https://menu.sharepoint.com/sites/top/SiteAssets/SPFXBranding/bootstrap.min.js"
    },
```

and since i'm just testing the bootstrap menu out i have the html for now hardcoded like below

```
export default class BootStrapTemplate {

    public static templateHtml: string = `
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navigation</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul> 

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) If you are adding jquery & bootstrap via CDN, no need to `npm` install them

2) `bootstap` components depend on `jQuery`. So, you need to first load jQuery and then bootstrap js. You can specify the loading order by `globalDependencies` attribute

3) You can then import these libraries in your files using the `import` statement.

So, modify your config.json file as below, I am using global CDN, but you can change the path as per your environment requirements:

```
"externals": {
    "jquery": {
      "path": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js",
      "globalName": "jquery"
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "path": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "globalName": "bootstrap",
      "globalDependencies": ["jquery"]
    }
  },
```

After that, in your webpart typescript file, make the below mentioned changes:

1) add following import statements:

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';

import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
```

2) Add a constructor and then change the render method as below:

```
export default class TestspfxWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ITestspfxWebPartProps> {

  public constructor() {
    super();

    SPComponentLoader.loadCss("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");
  }

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navigation</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul> 

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>`;


  }
```

Comment: Gautam thanks alot. Although i was working on an extension but the changes in the config.json worked like a charm.Thanks